# How to generate 8 digits UNIQUE & RANDOM number in C#

Tags: c#, numbers, unique

Does any body know, how to create unique & random 8 digits number? There are methods to create  random numbers, but my requirement is to create an unique also it should be a random number with 8 digits. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean with  unique? A random number that is unique with previous random numbers? In that case it is not a real random number. Otherwise just use random.NextDouble().

Comment: How do you define "unique"? If you generate 10^9 of these numbers, you'll run out of "unique" random numbers very quickly. If you need something unique that can be more than just 8 digits, try `Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: `0000004` // guaranteed random, chosen by the roll of a dice.

Comment: Do you perhaps require a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'unique'. There are only so many 8 digit numbers. It's like trying to generate a unique & random 2 digit numbers (it gets harder after about 100 goes).

Comment: @Jamiec That's only 7 digits. (And you still get upvotes! :p )

Comment: @Rawling - Damn it. Epic failure.

Comment: @Nolonar Guid will returns more than 8 characters...i'm supposed to make that work with 8 digits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int myRandomNo= rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999); // creates a 8 digit random no.
```

Comment: Does nothing to guarantee its uniqueness though as the OP asked.

Comment: Is there any way of maintain the uniqueness of this myRandomNo within the range provided to rnd.Next() method?

Comment: The `maxValue` for the upper-bound in the `Next()` method is __exclusive__ , unlike the `minValue`, which is __inclusive__. This means the range includes `minValue`, `maxValue-1`, and all numbers in between.

To properly include _all_ 8 digit numbers the correct call to `Next()` should be
`rnd.Next(10000000, 100000000)`

Comment: Do not guarantee uniqueness. This can be a serious issue in production